# Android Studio is importing the wrong packages

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I recently migrated to Android Studio,
but it still isn't polished (in my opinion).
When I was making a call to a new thread and trying to get a callback to the UI thread, it suddenly complained that there was no `post` method in the Handler class.

Then I noticed that the IDE had imported `java.util.logging.Handler` instead of `android.os.Handler`.
Has anyone encountered this same problem before and how do you get Android Studio to import properly?

Comment: Yes i had the same issue, but simply when using auto complete press (ctrl+space) twice it will show all classes that have named Handler with their packages, and select the proper one

Comment: Oh, I see. You should post that in an answer so I can mark this question solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes i had the same issue, but simply when using auto complete press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> *(check your keymap)* twice it will show all classes that have named Handler with their packages, and select the proper one